# Tortoise Mercurial change group repository url for existing local repository

Tags: mercurial

Hey I'm using mercurial tortoise for version control of my projects one of my group repositories got corrupted and I would like to change the repository URL to the new one that is working how do I go about that.

Comment: Do [homework](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change or add the new URLs to the `paths` section in your `.hg/hgrc` file. You can define different paths to groups or servers, for example:

```
#hgrc
[paths]
default = /somewhere/in/the/local/repository
group01 = https://example.com//absolute/path/in/remote/server/repository
...
```

As [manual](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#url-paths) explains there are the special `default` and `default-push` paths.